# Use txt files or sqlite with core data in project?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I am developing iPhone app for a web application currently running online. Current web application is big and complex and uses SQL to store vital information like member details, login credentials etx. Other stuffs like info about several sections, groups, sub groups and other information related to each are saved in txt. Current system uses its own standard to keep data in files and also made custom algorithm to read and write data in it. Each txt file is below 1 mb size. There are lot of data manipulations going on.
Custom algorithm created just read those files and put all data in cache as records (same as in core data managedobjectcontext) and whenever there is a change in data the whole file is overwritten.

So while implementing the same what I want to choose for iPhone app? In apple website they said that 'SQLite is perfect for low-level relational database work' https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/data-management.html But in my case it is high level.

So please help me to make a decision. Do I want to manage data in files or sqlite database using core data? 
I would also like to know whether it is possible to import those classes and algorithms currently in webserver to iOS, so I don't want to rewrite the same algorithm for iOS? Current server codes are in C#

Comment: While not exactly duplicate, this might be similar to [Android case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645183/arguments-for-and-against-the-android-sqlite-usage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the rare case that you need to do low-level relational database work use SQLite. In the 99% other cases use Core Data. Don't ever store relational stuff into txt files. It'll just be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case sounds like a good match for Core Data.

Often misunderstood, Core Data is an object store that happens to use sqlite for persistence. You don't manipulate the sqlite underneath it, Core Data manage the sqlite for you. You do not write SQL. The closest match to it in .NET is EDM and the Entity Framework in ADO.NET.

Assuming the classes and algorithm you want to import in the webserver is in C#, sadly those needed to be ported to Obj-C.